# How to create a non-breaking en-dash in Word 2003?

Tags: microsoft-word-2003

I have an en-dash between two words, and I am following the usual British rule (as advised in e.g. the [Oxford University style guide](https://www.ox.ac.uk/sites/files/oxford/media_wysiwyg/University%20of%20Oxford%20Style%20Guide.pdf)) of surrounding it with space characters. Using Word 2003, running on Windows 10 Pro, how can I ensure, other than by using a soft return which might well yield a too-short line after a future edit, that the en-dash appears at the start of a line rather than the end of one?

I've tried the following without success:

- non-breaking spaces before and after it
- a breaking space before it and a non-breaking one after
- a breaking space before it and a non-breaking one after it, with the latter wrapped in no-width non-breaks.

Comment: You are going to have a hard time simply because Word 2003 has been out of support for so long and has security problems.